# jQuery .attr() function within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am trying to dynamically replace attributes via jQuery – inside my for loop I am making use of an [.attr()-function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and it works fine but JSLint is complaining:

> Don't make functions within a loop.

I know that I can disable these specific test in the JSLint config but I want to understand how I could solve this by placing a corresponding function outside the loop and call that one accordingly when using .attr()

**Old logic**

```
for (var i = currentRowIndex + 1; i <= oldIndex; i++) {

  [...]

  selectorName.attr( 'name', function( index, name ) {
    return name.replace( /\d+/g, newIndex );
  } );
}
```

**Desired logic**

```
var replaceAttr = function( index, attr ) {
  return attr.replace( /\d+/g, index );
};

for (var i = currentRowIndex + 1; i <= oldIndex; i++) {

  [...]

  selectorName.attr( 'name', replaceAttr( function( newIndex, name ) );
}
```

**The problem**

While the first one works nicely and targets / passes the name-attribute correctly the second code simply replaces an empty attribute. Still being quite new to JS I am not sure how to tackle this...

- Is there a problem with closure?
- How can I pass / set the target so that it is recognized and not just a string?
- Would creating a 'master'-function which includes the .attr()-step help?

Looking forward to learning about this :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create the ids to be numeric, then define the selector in the loop as `$('#id'+ i).attr('attribute', 'value;);`

Comment: `function( newIndex, 'name' ) ` here `name` as a string not variable parameter

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs What do you mean by that? My IDs are fine, the selctors work, I just didn't post the full code but can add that if needed...

Comment: Probably don't need the `for()` loop. Show more code context and how `selectorName` is defined

Comment: The problem is, you did not show code of `selectorName ` function

Comment: @RuhulAmin I was working on demoing the code but then I saw that the answer from Jamiec worked already. Hope you didn't downvote the question because of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a slight error with externalising your function. The call to `attr` can take a function, but that means *your* function needs to return a function - this is often referred to as a closure.

```
var replaceAttr = function(newIndex){
 return  function( index, attr ) {
   return attr.replace( /\d+/g, newIndex );
 }
}

for (var i = currentRowIndex + 1; i <= oldIndex; i++) {

  [...]

  selectorName.attr( 'name', replaceAttr(newIndex) );
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks, will have to do some more work on closures then...!